# Python читать сокет определенное количество времени

Tags: python

Как реализовать чтение сокета определенное количество времени. Хочу в цикле вызывать 
data = socket.recv()
 столько сколько требуется. И иметь возможность прервать цикл если например data="stop".
Socket.settimeout подойдёт только если ждать одну пачку данных, а мне неважно сколько данных важно время.

Comment: На первый взгляд, можно поместить чтение сокета в функцию и создать процесс c этой функцией в качестве цели: `multiprocessing.Process(target=...)` После того дождаться его завершения с нужным таймаутом (например, 6 секунд): `p.join(timeout=6)` (после этого нужно будет сделать ещё `p.terminate()`)

Comment: Забыл написать, что `p` и есть этот процесс `p = multiprocessing.Process(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Идея может быть такой:

Устанавливаете обработчик сигнала:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
```

Задаёте желаемый интервал времени:

```
 signal.alarm(time)
```

И начинаете бесконечный цикл чтения из сокета.

```
flag = 1
while flag=1:
     Читаем сокет
```

Обработчик прерывания сбрасывает флажок выполнения цикла чтения из сокета.

```
def handler():
    flag = 0
```

После завершения цикла (по любому способу) надо сбросить обработчик сигнала:

```
signal.alarm(0)
```